# How to get a value from an incomplete class object in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object

I have a serialized PHP object, which looks the following when I unserialize it:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => model_Baubeschreibung
    [prototype:persistence_Table:private] => Array
        (
            [model_Baubeschreibung] => Array
                (
                    [table] => rp_baubeschreibung
                    // ... some more stuff here
                )
        )
    [table:persistence_Table:private] => rp_baubeschreibung
    [id:persistence_Table:private] => 170
    [properties:persistence_Table:private] => Array
        (
            [name] => MY NAME
            [description] => MY DESCRIPTION
            [category] => MY CATEGORY
        )

    [references:persistence_Table:private] => Array
        (
            // Some more stuff here
        )
    [objects:persistence_Table:private] => Array
        (
        )
    [callback:persistence_Table:private] => Array
        (
        )
    [state:persistence_Table:private] => 2
);
```

I don't have the option to load the class that this object refers to.

Is there any way that I can get the values '`MY NAME`',  '`MY DESCRIPTION`',  '`MY CATEGORY`', and the id (here: 170) from the object? At best without a preg_match.
I tried looping through the object but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include class definition before unserializing the object. Use proper autoloader or just include the class.

When you do it. It will be properly casted to object of your class.

Comment: Well thats the problem, I don't have the class defenition, I only have that serialized string with the object

Comment: You can cast it to stdClass or use `get_object_vars()`

Comment: get_object_vars didn't work, I actually came along the class definition, including it solved the problem, thanks for your halp

Answer (score 0):

Cast as array and read properties:

```
$unserializedObject = unserialize($string);
$array = (array)$unserializedObject;
var_dump($array["\0persistence_Table\0properties"]);
              // ^                  ^
              // these null bytes are required!
```